# Connection between rank one matrices and rank one functions

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, rank-1-matrices

Let $X$ be a finite set and $\mathbb{F}$ be a field. We say that a function
$f: X\times X \to \mathbb{F}$ is **rank one** if $f$ is of the form $(x,y) \mapsto a(x)b(y)$ for $a,b: X \to \mathbb{F}$. (See [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2016/05/18/a-symmetric-formulation-of-the-croot-lev-pach-ellenberg-gijswijt-capset-bound/) for instance in Tao's set up for the slice rank formulation of the Croot-Lev-Pach polynomial method).

I understand that a matrix $A \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$, (for instance) is of rank one if and only if $A = \mathbf{v}\mathbf{w}^t$ for some $\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. However, the connection between the functional definition and the matrix definition has always been unclear to me.

To be explicit about my questions:

1. Are we interpreting the function $f: X\times X \to \mathbb{F}$ as a function that, in some sense, "populates" the entries of a $|X| \times |X|$ matrix?
2. Can we interpret $f: X^k \to \mathbb{F}$ as a function that "populates" the entries in a $$\underbrace{|X|\times |X| \times \cdots \times |X|}_{k\text{-times}}$$ hypermatrix?
3. In the literature, $f$ as defined in (1) and (2) are said to be tensors (see for instance [this paper by Gowers](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.08394)).  What is the connection between these tensors and the tensors as they are defined in Dummit and Foote (say). I have done some playing around and searching around to try and get a satisfactory answer concerning this connection but have not been very successful. Do you have a hint as to how I can discover this connection? I think I am missing something that is supposedly obvious.

If these questions are too lengthy to answer in a short amount of time, what references would you suggest I look into to gain a better understanding?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very nice answer to the above question can be found in Chapter 2 of the below monograph:

[Tensors: Geometry and Applications by J.M. Landsberg](https://www.math.tamu.edu/%7Ejml/Tbookintro.pdf)